# Ternary function return Nan in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, conditional-operator

**Code:**

```
function sumfunct(x,y)
{
    let sum = 0;
    sum = (x === null ? 0 : x) + (y === null ? 0 : y);
    return sum;
}
```

if one of the input values are null then it returns **Nan**

Please help me to return some value

Comment: If a function is called without one or more argument, the value in the function is `undefined`, not `null`.

Comment: 1) `undefined === null => false`; 2) `1 + undefined => NaN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript all those values: (0, undefined, null, false, '') Will return false.

If you use the triple = like ===. This check also the TYPE. So if you have undefined as a value, this will not be === to null.

Check the simple function here, this may solve your problem.

```js
function sumfunct(x,y)
{
    let sum = 0;
    sum = (x ? x : 0) + (y ? y : 0);
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add default values to your function arguments.

```
const sum = (x = 0, y = 0) => x + y;
```

In case they are `null` or `undefined` values will be 0;

For a better handle you can use something like:

```
const sum = (x, y) => {
  const a = Number.isFinite(+x) ? +x : 0;
  const b = Number.isFinite(+y) ? +y : 0;
  return a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic operator `===` matches both type and value. If you don't pass an argument the default value is `undefined` which is not null, hence you add a number to undefined.

```
function sumfunct(x,y)
{
    let sum = 0;
    sum = (!x ? 0 : x) + (!y ? 0 : y);
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the default value as a `0`.`undefine` and `null` replace with `0`

```js
function sumfunct(x=0,y=0)
{
    let sum = 0;
    sum = x + y;
    return sum;
}

sumfunct(console.log(sumfunct(2, undefined)))
sumfunct(console.log(sumfunct(2, null)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just check both inputs separately as well

```js
function sumfunct(x,y)
{
    x = (x === null ? 0 : x);
    y = (y === null ? 0 : y);
    return x+y;
}

console.log(sumfunct(2,2));
console.log(sumfunct(2,null));
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter way to do it. Every `falsey` value (`0`, `null` or `undefined`) would be transform to 0:

```
function sumfunct(x,y)
{
    let sum = 0;
    sum = (x || 0) + (y || 0);
    return sum;
}
```

---

#### Try snippet here

```js
function sumfunct(x,y)
{
    let sum = 0;
    sum = (x || 0) + (y || 0);
    return sum;
}

console.log(sumfunct(2, 2));   // 4
console.log(sumfunct(3));     // 3
console.log(sumfunct(null, 2));   // 2
console.log(sumfunct(undefined, undefined));   // 0
```

Comment: ... at which point, `sum` is irrelevant, and this could be written as `const sumFunct = (x, y) => (x || 0) + (y || 0)`